# Python Bbcode to HTML translation

Tags: python, html, bbcode

i'm working with python 3.4.4 32bits (work rules), and i'm implementing a program that takes bbcode lines from a .txt file, and then converting those into a HTML lines, to be readed for PyQt5 elements with Qt.RichText. For me is not allowed  to type HTML lines in thoses .txt files, so i just need to take those bbcode lines, read them, translated into a HTML that's all. I've tried to use the bbcode module, version 1.0.31, specifically the function `bbcode.render_html(bbcodeContent)` the problem is: that function doesn´t recognize most of the normal bbcode lines such as tables for example, that means, this functions doesn't translate properly to HTML tables.
To be specific if a have in the `bbcodeContent` variable the following:

```
[table border=1 align=center]
[tr]
[td align=center colSpan=2][b][i]text[/i][/b][/color][/td]
[/tr]
[tr]
[td]text[/td]
[td]text[/td]
[/tr]
[/table]
```

The result at the printing of the function `bbcode.render_html(bbcodeContent)` is:

```
[table border=1 align=center]<br />
[tr]<br />
[td align=center colSpan=2]<strong><em>text</em></strong>[/td]<br />
[/tr]<br />
[tr]<br />
[td]text[/td]<br />
[td]text[/td]<br />
[/tr]<br />
[/table]
```

That is clearly not properly HTML as suppose, but as said, not only tables, but most of the simple bbcodes are not recognized. for the past input the expected output could be:

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><strong><em>text</em></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text</td><td>text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The question hier is clear: How can i correct this problem with this bbcode module? I'm doing something wrong?

Now i'm using a new python module called bbcodepy.py founded hier https://github.com/vishnevskiy/bbcodepy installed manually and did some modifications and now the complete issue is solved, but that module is so old to trust in, that means i really want to try the official bbcode module. Can you give a hand with it?

Comment: the page of the module explains how to do it in a very simple way.

Comment: My friend, your comment don't help me. I went to the main page http://bbcode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tags.html and realized, there are those "built in Tags", those doesn't include the tables, and several other things. The solution could be somehow adding the missing objects, but It is assumed that this module should have them, that's what the module is for.

Comment: *you* are assuming things

Comment: here's the link: https://github.com/dcwatson/bbcode. read it slowly, carefully. show some effort